# Dynamically setting column names in MySQL based on dictionary

Tags: mysql

I have a genericlog table that stores columns like:

text_1, 
text_2, 
text_3, 
...

The meaning of these columns, and the data defined within, are meant to be entirely generic. An external dictionary will define the meaning, based on application, version, and type. What I need to be able to do is run a query against genericlog that returns the proper column names for that row.

Notice this invalid SQL statement that tries to rename text_1 as the joined dictionary record defines:

```
select gl.text_1 as gd.text_1
from log.genericlog gl 
left join log.genericlog_dictionary gd on 
gd.version = gl.version and 
gd.application = gl.application and 
gd.type = gl.type;
```

I want the query to return the column names that the dictionary defines, so text_1 actually gets returned as "employeeid" or whatever the application+version+type defines text_1 to be in the dictionary.

Without iterating over the result set, is this possible to do directly in the query?

Here's an image of the (theoretical) table structure
 [image]

Comment: You need to write dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Can you elaborate a bit? If I use dynamic sql, it seems I'd just be concating in exactly one possible column name for text_1, rather than the column name that matches that row's version+app+type. Since text_1 could have more than one possible name, do you have an idea of how the dynamic SQL would work?

Comment: Dynamic SQL means you write a query that creates a new query, which you then execute. So the first query will put the appropriate value in the `AS` clause, then prepare and execute this new query.

Comment: I am not sure that will work. The dynamic SQL would not be doing a row-dependent injection, it would naming text_1 the same for all rows in the result set.

Comment: A result set can only have one column name for each column, not a different name for each row.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant rows. The end result is definitely possible - a table that has columns text_1, text_2, text_3, ..., renamed to timezone, datetime_utc, location_id, etc., where some rows that don't have a corresponding dictionary entry for a given column name would just be null. I think I will need to iterate over the result set in PHP and remap column names by using the dictionary definition for that row.

Comment: But if different rows have a different `application`, `version` or `type`, they would need different column headings. That can't work. This can only be done if you're selecting a specific application, type, and version so that all the dictionary entries are the same.

Comment: Right, which is why I wanted to avoid dynamic SQL. Basically this can be done easily in PHP by returning genericlog rows as-is, then foreach row, lookup the dictionary defintion for that application, version, and type, then use array_map() to rename the keys of that associative array to match the dictionary. Any keys not defined in that app+version+type would be populated with null. The end result would be an amalgamation of all possible column names from all versions for all rows, with nulls in place of values for columns that version did not define.

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample contents of the tables and the final desired results.

Comment: Agreed @Barmar I have added a link to the theoretical table structure. It's kind of funky, I know, but if I can do it, this would solve several problems. Of course, using a system like this would all have to center around proper use of conventions, but it would be great to be able to extract fields you care about - e.g. "userid" - across versions even if one version didn't implement that field.

Comment: You wrote that this is theoretical. Does that mean you can change the table design?

Comment: Yes, table design can be changed ad hoc. It's part of a new SOAP service.